# What is the connection string for connecting to MySql from Azure Cloud Service web application?

Tags: mysql, .net, azure, ssl, connection-string

We have a MySql database with SSL turned on.

We have an Azure Cloud Service where we install our certificate.

We are using v6.9.9 of the .Net MySql Connector.

See below - does anyone see what we are doing wrong? Is the connection string correct? Can someone explain, in a cloud environment on Azure, what the "certificate location" is?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Based on these links:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/
```

We are using a connection string that looks like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
SSL Mode=Required;Certificate Store Location=CurrentUser;
Certificate Thumbprint=479436009a40f3017a145cf8479e7694d7aadef0;
```

The problem -- when I run our code, I get a MySql exception:

**Keyword not supported. Parameter name: certificate thumbprint**

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connStr)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)

**Update:**
Part of the problem is that the 'space' in Certificate Store Location and Certificate Thumbprint. I've removed those spaces, and also tried to use the location as "LocalMachine"

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
SSL Mode=Required;CertificateStoreLocation=LocalMachine;
CertificateThumbprint=479436009a40f3017a145cf8479e7694d7aadef0;
```

However, my new error is:

**Certificate with Thumbprint 479436009a40f3017a145cf8479e7694d7aadef0 not found**

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetClientCertificates() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL()at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()  at Cmm.Data.MySql.MySqlContext.get_DbConnection()

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the certificate to your cloud service first, and then change the certificate location to "**LocalMachine**".

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, tried this but still getting certificate with thumprint .... not found. We installed the certificate in Azure already, and used the thumprint listed there, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you know if we have to "configure" our Cloud Service (both a Web Role and Worker Role) with the certificate? I thought uploading via the Azure Portal was sufficient, and that configuring in the Cloud Service config in Visual Studio was for the web HTTPS side of things only?

Comment: Yes. You need to configure the cloud services with the certificate. Try to upload the certificate to the cloud services.